# Phone answer or hangs up when it rings and I take the phone out of my pocket

Tags: 7.0-nougat, calls

When the phone rings and I pull it out of my pocket, most of the time it either hangs up or answers the call. I don't touch any buttons with my fingers. Sometimes it does this even before I start to take it out of my pocket. This is not in bluetooth mode. Phone is set to stay locked until I swipe the pattern or use fingerprint.
Ideally I want the phone to only answer when I explicitly tell it to do so.

Model SM-G930V
Android version 7.0

Comment: Do you any  gestures enabled? Lift to check phone enabled?

Comment: I don't know, how do I check?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but open Settings and navigate to Moves, which can be found in the System section.

Comment: There is no Moves section in settings on my phone

Comment: check answer below @user3561494

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I dug a little deeper and read the user guide/manual for your phone. It might be some settings that are enabled in the accessibility settings, called Single Tap mode. Here is the [link to the user guide.](https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=http://www.galaxys7manual.com/wp-content/uploads/manual/samsung_galaxy_s7_manual_SM_G930_Marshmallow_English.pdf&hl=en_US) I included a screenshot of that section and added the text too.

[image]

> When an alarm sounds or a call comes in, tap the button to stop the
>   alarm or answer the call instead of dragging the button.

On the Apps screen, tap Settings → Accessibility, and then tap the Single tap mode switch to activate it.

> Change the method of answering or ending calls.

On the Apps screen, tap Settings → Accessibility → Answering and ending calls. Select the desired method.